# Sistema Angular e Spring para homologar

Tags: spring, angular

Temos uma VM na azure.

Gerei o build de homologação e coloquei no servidor.

Gerou os arquivos e o index.html assim

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DESIF</title>
  <base href="/">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

  <app-root>Carregando ...</app-root>

<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

No servidor Tomcat. na pasta **Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps**, criei a pasta **dist**.

Ao entrar com o endereço: **http://endereco:8080/dist**, ele vai a página correta, ao carregar muda o endereço para **http://endereco:8080/#/login**, o que é correto, mas imaginei que seria: **http://endereco:8080/dist/#/login**

Se aperto **F5** ou **CTRL + F5**, ele vai para inicial do TOMCAT.

Tenho que configurar algo ?

No Angular, tenho um arquivo que tem o endereço do Servidor, no caso é **http://localhost:8080/sistema*, para não ter que ficar mudando toda vez que subir para homologação, tem como o angular fazer isto automático, por alguma variável ?

Primeira vez que faço um deploy.

Existe alguma maneira melhor ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Alterei o Html, esta parte de **< base href="/">** para **< base href="./">**, e assim funcionou.

Mas tem alguma outra maneira que faço sem ter que ficar alterando o html ?

Tem como fazer uma variável para servidor de homologação, produção e desenvolvimento, pois os mesmos mudam, no angular ?